# How to update values of filtered cells of a column in excel using vba macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update the filtered values of a column using vba macros. Eg. Flag column has values Y and N and I have filtered to N. Now I want to update the value "N" to some other value.  Below is a sample image. Can someone please suggest ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to update **all** the items or only the **visible** items???

Comment: Only the visible items i.e. row 6 to 9

Comment: So basically a multi criterial filter?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey - Its a single filter here.

Comment: You want the VBA code to filter column A for "N" values? Something like: Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="N" ? Check also this link in case: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey - Thanks, but I know how to filter the data in a column. My question is that I want to change the values of cells associated with a filtered column.(please refer to the image that I have attached in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Framm()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1)

    For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        cell.Value = "changed"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Sub SubChangeAutofilteredValues()

    'Declarations.
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim StrOldValue As String
    Dim StrNewValue As String

    'Setting variables.
    StrOldValue = "N"
    StrNewValue = "K"

    'Autofiltering.
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=StrOldValue

    'Verifying if any match has been found.
    If Cells(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No records found.", , "No records found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Setting the variable.
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
        Set RngRange01 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    'Changing the values.
    RngRange01.Value = StrNewValue

End Sub
```